# how to read only headers from response and cancel all the rest using c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, stream, byte, response

a server that i want to work with it return `302 Found` with some body bytes here is the raw

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: unknown
Date: Sun, 29 Jun 2014 20:12:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
x-powered-by: 
Set-Cookie: session=604d0bdba04eb54793ec2f3c98b2a37e; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: www.mysite.com/login.php?session=604d0bdba04eb54793ec2f3c98b2a37e
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 18163
```

**this body bytes i want to cancel it from being downloaded :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
///////body bytes about 18kb///////
</html>
```

here is my code manupulating the response using asynchorous request :

```
  Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(asynchronousResult.AsyncState, HttpWebRequest)


        Dim BYTES_TO_READ As Integer = 0
        Dim buffer = New Byte(BYTES_TO_READ - 1) {}

        Using response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult), HttpWebResponse)
            Using sm As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim totalBytesRead As Integer = 0
                Dim bytesRead As Integer
                Do
                    bytesRead = sm.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead, BYTES_TO_READ - totalBytesRead)
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead
                Loop While totalBytesRead < BYTES_TO_READ
                request.Abort()
                response.Close()
                sm.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        Dim s = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer)
       Console.WriteLine(s)
    Catch ex As WebException
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

the output is null but the response is fully downloaded ! and i want to skip this i want only headers and cancel all the rest of the `response stream`

**so is there any method to read only the headers and cancel all the remaning bytes**

Comment: If you don't want the data, don't read it. Just dispose everything.

Comment: @usr thanks for your support ! and whene i dispose everything can i read the headers ? and the the body bytes will not be downloaded ?

Comment: Well, you obviously dispose everything *after* reading the headers. Hopefully, this will close the connection.

Answer (score 2):

To read headers you should check response.Headers collection, without calling GetResponseStream. Have you tried this, is entire body downloaded anyway?

Another thing you may try - is to request data using 'HEAD' request. It is specifically designed to retrieve only headers, always without body.

Comment: this response is a result of "POST" i can not use "HEAD"

Comment: I believe this is inevitable and dictated by http - if you started downloading http response, you need to also download body. Probably custom http implementation can drop connection after receiving header, but this would be a violation of protocol. Why are you trying to optimize this? To save traffic? Its only 18kb

Comment: this is multithreading about 5000 request and i have nothing to do with the 18kb i want only headers